# How can I trace a placeholder to find its controller?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, asp.net-placeholder

I'm trying to clean up a registration form. The precursors made it easy to adjust most sections of this form, but when I get to the Address portion of the template I uncovered this strange artifact:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phAddress" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>          
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The directory system for this site is extensive but I've had luck tracking stuff using text searches of file content.  However, with this one searching for "phAddress" gets me nowhere.

[image]

=================================================

[image]

=================================================

[image]

Comment: Probably populated from the code behind. Check the C#/VB file.

Comment: This is from a .xsl template file that is inside of a directory called "Template".  It's the only file in there and there are no subdirectories.  I've checked the files and folders of its parent to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and search for the text `phAddress` with the option selected as "Entire Solution".

As its "PlaceHolder" there is a possibility that "dynamic controls" are added from the "codebehind(aspx.cs or aspx.vb)" page.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more of your code base, it's almost impossible to figure out what's being done. Typically, a `PlaceHolder` is just that - a placeholder for controls that are going to be generated dynamically server-side. Try doing a `Ctrl+F` for "phAddress" in the codebehind file. If you don't know what that is, take a look at the very top of the asp file, you should see something like this:

`<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="mypage.aspx.cs" Inherits="myprogject.mypage" %>`

`CodeBehind` is the class name, and `Inherits=` is the directory path of where it lives.

In VS 2010, here's what you're looking for:

[image: YAY PLAYGROUND]

This is a C# file, but the structure for VB should be same.

Comment: `<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="CustomerRegistration.ascx.vb"
    Inherits="Personify.DNN.Modules.CustomerRegistration.CustomerRegistration" %>`


Sweet!  I'm seeing what you're saying, but I don't have a file by this name.  Is it hiding somewhere?

Comment: Possibly, but I've never seen the code live in a different directory - but that doesn't mean it's not possible. If you can find `CustomerRegistration.ascx.vb` you'll be in business. I'm assuming you're using Visual Studio?

Comment: @NominalAeon sorry, I'm an idiot. You're looking for `Personify.DNN.Modules.CustomerRegistration.CustomerRegistration` -> That's your path.

Comment: Thanks for the responses!  I've updated the question to include some screenshots of the directory I'm working from and a couple of the folders next to it.  I searched the root for CustomerRegistration.ascx.vb and there were no results :\

*Just saw your new message.  I'm going back to follow that lead now...

Comment: Personify.DNN.Modules.CustomerRegistration.CustomerRegistration doesn't seem to be an existing path from any starting point

Comment: Hmm....I'm not seeing any `.vb` files....trying searching the root for just `.vb`? You've got my scratching my head and stroking my beard over here....

Comment: Yeah, there are about 30, and none of them seem relevant to the module I'm trying to adjust.  But it's okay, I've actually learned a couple of things I didn't know before so I feel more confidant sending this question in to the software provider... without sounding completely clueless.  Thanks again!